# Unable to locate package chntpw

Tags: live-cd, official-repositories

To overwrite a Windows 7 password, one can boot from a Ubuntu LiveCD and run chntpw.

Unfortunately, installing chntpw is not so easy:

```
$ sudo apt-get install chntpw
E: Unable to locate package chntpw
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't comment to @Nicolas Raoul, that's why I post this as a answer. Sorry for this. I have the same problem when trying to install boot-repair. I tried all this, but it still doesn't work. What can I do?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First open the **Ubuntu Software Center**, in the *Edit* menu click *Software Sources...*, and in the window that appears enable *universe* as seen below:

[image: Ubuntu enable universe]

Then run `sudo apt-get update`.

You should now be able to install chntpw using `sudo apt-get install chntpw`.

Comment: Works perfectly

Answer (score 9):

Do this from the terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install chntpw
```